# What is the point of VectorIndexer in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

[VectorIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer.html) has the following purpose as I understand it:

In `VectorUDT` typed columns it converts the values it deems categorical to numerical mappings

However, It operates only on `VectorUDT` types and these are necessarily already built of Numerical types. We convert categorical features to Numerical features since many ml algorithms do not work with non-numerical types. What is the point of mapping Numerical values to Numerical values which is what the `VectorIndexer` seems to be useful for?